# How do I see a list of every cookie (including contents) for any domain in Chrome/Firefox/Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari

I know how to see the list of cookies for the current site, but sometimes I want to see cookies for other sites.

Inside Google Chrome, I can see which sites I have cookies stored for, but I cannot see their contents.

How do I see a list of every cookie (including contents) for any site (domain) in Chrome/Firefox/Safari?

[image: chrome]